# jQuery UI Datepicker with AJAX dynamically created row

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I would be grateful for some help to get JQuery UI Datepicker to work with dynamically created rows.

A user can add additional rows (partial view) to a table to enable more data input (took this from Steven Sanderson's blog). This is achieved through AJAX. Adding rows works perfectly, but I want to enable jQuery UI Datepicker (http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc-part-4)  for some inputs in these dynamically created rows. I have got the Datepicker working where rows are not dynamically added but I just cannot work out how to get it to work my my AJAX. Thanks in advance.

**This is the code that creates the new row:**

```
$("#addItem").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $("#editorRows").append(html);
        },

    }); return false;


});
```

**This is the partial view new row:** ( I have added the [DataType(DataType.Date)] to the appropriate viewmodel fields)

```
@model ef_tut.ViewModels.LineViewModel
@using ef_tut.Models
@using ef_tut.ViewModels
@using ef_tut.WebUI.Helpers

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("LineViewModels"))

{


<table class="editorRow">
<tr>
<td>
ClaimID: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClaimID)</td>
<td>
ClaimLineID: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClaimLineID)</td>
     <td>

ClaimantUserID: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Selecteduserid, new SelectList(Model.users, "UserID", "FirstName"))</td>
    <td >
CatID: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Selectedcatid, new SelectList(Model.categories, "CatID", "CatName"))</td>
<td >
SubCatID: @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SubCatID)</td>
<td>
Comments: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comments)</td>
<td>
HoursCost: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HoursCost)</td>
<td >
MeetingDate: @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MeetingDate )</td>
<td>
MileageCost: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MileageCost)</td>
<td>
ProxyClaim: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProxyClaim)</td>
<td>
TotalCost: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TotalCost)</td>
<td>
TravelCost: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TravelCost)</td>
    <td>
Venue: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Venue)</td>
<td>
Hours: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Hours)</td>

    <td>
<a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
</td>
</tr></table>



}
```

THis is the .js that hooks up the datepicker.

```
$(document).ready(function () { $('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" }); });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to have to hook up the datepicker for the new row(s) in the success event.

```
$("#addItem").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.href,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (html) {
                        $("#editorRows").append(html);
                        $('#editorRows .date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
                    },

                }); return false;


            });
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Things you should Consider :

1. Make sure you are applying datepicker when document is ready .
   Do it under `document.getready` function
2. Apply common class on all the `textbox` where you have to apply datepicker .
   then do it like

   $('.DatepickerClass').datepicker()

i have used another `jquery datepicker` but this things should work on your ajax `datepicker` too.

Comment: I thought document ready only applies to when the page was originally loaded. My issue is with dynamically created rows. All inputs have the .date class.